# Reduce multiple file upload time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am uploading multiple images and videos with input[type='file'],
The upload takes a lot of time.
Is there any way I can reduce the upload time.
Here is my current code:

**Paperclip settings**

```
     has_attached_file :file, styles: lambda { |a| a.instance.check_file_type}
  validates_attachment_content_type :file, content_type: [/\Aimage\/.*\Z/,/\Avideo\/.*\Z/]

  def is_video?
    file.content_type =~ %r(video)
  end

  def is_image?
    file.content_type =~ %r(image)
  end

  def check_file_type
    if is_image?
      { :medium => { :geometry => "640x480" },
      :thumb => { :geometry => "100x100#" } }
    elsif is_video?
      { :medium => { :geometry => "640x480", :format => 'mp4', :processors => [:transcoder] },
      :thumb => { :geometry => "100x100#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10 }}
    else
      {}
    end
  end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@room, remote: true, format: :js, authenticity_token: true, html: {multipart: true}) do |f| %>
   *******other fields***********
    <input id="video-selector" type="file" name="files[]" accept="video/*,image/*" capture="camcorder" hidden="true" class="hide" multiple
                   onchange="$('#upload-file-info').addClass('label-info').append(this.files[0].name);">
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this link to upload multiple files
https://www.sitepoint.com/asynchronous-multiple-file-upload-with-rails-and-dropzone-js/